# Find index of filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
var JSON = {
    "implants":[{
        "familyId": "3",
        "reference": "1234",
        "quantity": "3"
    },{
        "familyId": "2",
        "reference": "3456",
        "quantity": "1"
    }]
}
```

I'm building a function which searches whether an implant with the given "reference" is already in the array. If it's not, it just gets added to the array. Easy. If it *is* in the array, then I want to add the new quantity to the existing quantity and then update the array.

```
function returnTheseImplantsWhere(key1,key2){
    return function(el){
        if(el[key1]==key2) {
            return el;
        }
    } 
}

var activeCaseImplants = JSON.parse(getLocal("activeCaseImplants"));
var existingImplant = activeCaseImplants.implants.filter(returnTheseImplantsWhere("reference", window.currentImplantRef));
if(existingImplant.length) {
    //previously added implant
    newImplantQty = Number(existingImplant[0].quantity) + Number($("#qty").val());
    existingImplant.quantity = newImplantQty;
} else {
    //new implant
}
```

My question relates to the "previously added implant" section of the above code (which all works as expected). I now have the updated quantity, but I can I determine which object within the activeCaseImplants.implants array needs it's quantity updated? I feel like I could make use of `indexOf` somewhere around the line beginning with `var existingImplant = ...` but I'm not sure where or how. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `reference` property unique?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, so the object that you will get after `filter` will be the same one as of array. Just update quantity in it

Comment: @CodingIntrigue yes.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. I'm not sure I understand. The `activeCaseImplants` array is the full array of all objects. The `existingImplant` variable is just a single object with with the reference in question. I can update the `existingImplant` object with the new quantity, but then how can I insert that updated object back in to the `activeCaseImplants` array - I need to know the index of that object in the `activeCaseImplants` array so I know which one to update.

Comment: @Brad Please refer following sample: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/k4t8np0p/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, can you please explain what `x=>x.familyId === id` is doing?

Comment: As an aside, after I update the quantity from 1 to 2, when I `console.log(existingImplant)`, I get: `{familyId: "2", reference: "3456", quantity: "1"}` but when I `console.log(existingImplant.quantity)` I get `2`. Why might that be?

Comment: @Rajesh, I can see that your code is doing what I need, but I don't really understand what's happening. How does `var obj = JSON.implants.filter(function(x){ return x.reference === ref })[0];` and then `obj.quantity = +obj.quantity + 1;` alter the `JSON` variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127265/discussion-between-rajesh-and-brad).